# Stack Overflow Jobs Update - August 2018

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

Here’s a round up of what’s been happening on Jobs recently.

#### Improved remote labels

Remote jobs are some of the most sought after jobs but there are nuances to remote work that weren’t entirely transparent to you. Some companies offer remote positions but require employees to be in a certain timezone while others might require you to be in-office once a week or a few times a year.

[Gervasio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920295/g3rv4?tab=profile) added the ability for employers to include specific details about remote work so that you can make informed decisions when you consider an opportunity.

If employers offer remote work, they must choose between “On-site and limited remote” or “Remote.” If the job is limited remote, then they must add a location and have the option to include additional notes. If they job is fully remote, they have the option to include timezone preferences as well as the option to work in office.

Remote details such as time zones requirements or employer notes are displayed on the job listing.

*Fully remote example*

[image]

*Onsite with limited remote example*

[image]

#### Ability to exclude industries and companies in job preferences

[Aurélien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1370722/aur%C3%A9lien-gasser?tab=profile) added the ability to exclude specific companies and industries in job preferences. Your [job preferences](https://dev.stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current) help us send you better job recommendations. When you fill out your preferences, we treat them as hard filters when sending you job recommendations. So if you never want to see a job from Nope Inc. in your inbox, just exclude Nope Inc. in your preferences.

When it comes to [job search](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs), your job preferences act as weights when jobs are sorted by ‘matches’ rather than hard filters. Excluding a company or industry in your preferences will push these jobs to the bottom of your search list but won’t hide them altogether. Disliked tags operate in the same way.

One more thing to note — job ads run on a different system and don’t take job preferences into consideration, yet. However, dismissed jobs are synced across the job ads system and job recommendations so if you dismiss a job anywhere on site, you shouldn’t see that job pop up again as an ad or recommendation in your inbox.

[image: excluded industries]

[image: excluded companies]

#### Exposed job search and company search filters

Most of you are already familiar with the various job and company search filters available but a common piece of feedback we received through our monthly visitor survey was that it’d be great if you could filter by things like technologies, developer roles, or salary. This was a clear signal that although these filters are available, users had a hard time finding them.

[Ian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6347688/ian?tab=profile) and [Piper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7851896/piper-lawson?tab=profile) worked on exposing job and company filters, which were previously hidden behind a filter pane.

[image: job search filters]

#### Ability to undo an application

You may have experienced a time when you submitted an application, only to realize you attached the wrong resume or forgot to include a cover letter. Oops!

Gervasio added the ability to undo an application, immediately after it was submitted. When you submit an application, you’ll see an ‘undo’ link displayed in the success message. It only appears for a minute but it should help you out for those accidental moments.

[image: undo application]

#### Responsive design

[In tandem with Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness), Jobs is now responsive.  This effort is ongoing and we still have some areas to make responsive, like Developer Story, but most Jobs features can be carried out on smaller screen sizes.

#### Redesigned Company Pages

Company pages got a new look and feel.  [Kirti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012097/kirti-thorat?tab=profile) and [Courtny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3281191/courtny?tab=profile) reformatted the layout and styling to support new features down the line. They are now responsive and the underlying code was cleaned up significantly to help make it easier to add new features going forward.

Company pages serve two users. Companies, who want to have a presence on Stack Overflow to reach the wider developer audience and developers, who are searching for additional information about a company.

We’d like to improve company pages to offer more useful information. This part of the product is being refined to improve a developer’s ability to communicate with & about companies – learning not only about job opportunities but the products they build and developer cultures embedded within.

We are currently exploring ideas to better serve the developer community and are very interested in hearing from you what you’d find valuable or useful to see.

Our eyes and ears are open, and we’d love to hear from you. If you have thoughts, please post it as an answer below.

[image]

Comment: Looks good now, thank Des.

Comment: the unicorn... is it for sale?

Comment: @SagarV See [Where can I get a unicorn?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216179/318307)

Comment: Id appreciate it if the job adverts were optional.

Comment: Is there any way from where I can see the jobs applied to. I tried to find it under user settings but was unable to and can we provide some user feedback on the job there are several companies where I have applied but not gotten any response not even a rejection mail. can we report listings like this?

Comment: @PramodYadav you can view the jobs you applied to in your Messages https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages. Re: responses - we try to encourage employers to respond quickly to  applicants. For example, we tag employers that respond quickly with a "high response" flag on their jobs and company pages as a way to encourage more of that behavior.  Ideally, every applicant would get a response in a timely manner! Unfortunately, it's not something we can control and they aren't violating any of our policies by not responding. If anything, they are hurting their own image.

Answer (score 95):

One thing which I really dislike about Jobs (not just on SO, but in general) is that companies put "Junior, Mid-level, Senior" for almost all their postings.

I opened the Jobs page and [saw this at the start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZM9m.png). The job posting is for "Senior Staff Engineer at HBO" and the experience level marked is Junior. They need people who are at least 5 years experienced. I've been searching for Jobs and sorting for "Junior" has always been polluted by jobs which need 3+ years of experience after grad (considering 3 years as the Junior limit).

Can we have an explicit "Experience (years)" field alongside the "Experience level" field?

(I get it that such companies can still fill in 1-10 directly, but this probably would be less prevalent than choosing "Junior" for a senior job)

Comment: That's a great point, thanks for the feedback. We want job data to accurately reflect what the employer is looking for. If you come across a job like this where there seems to be a discrepancy between requirements, you can certainly flag it. Our support team will follow up with the employer and ask them to update the listing. I went ahead and reported the one you mentioned for now.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that I could report those jobs. That's something really good. Thanks for informing me about this.

Comment: well _I'm a fresher with 1 + 6 years experience_

Comment: Also this "Junior vs Senior" is quite subjective in my experience...

Comment: @EMBarbosa: Indeed. I would expect that a minimum level of experience is required to become a Senior; however I've had colleagues with over 15 years of experience who still behaved like Juniors (ie: little autonomy, little initiative, no mentoring).

Comment: @MatthieuM. Exactly. **"Years of experience"** number is very similar to **age** - cannot be taken as the only indicator of how one's attitude, reliability or keenness is. Some people literally _"stop"_ after they reach 25.

Comment: @Skipper:  Well, general advise for resume experience is to not say more than 20 years because that suggests one is a rusty old fossil.

Comment: I fairly regularly flag jobs that are tagged [unity3d] despite not being developer roles (and by "regularly" I mean "about one every six to eight weeks").

Comment: "Wow, I didn't know that I could report those jobs" I think that's a bug @Des for the UX team.